# How do I plot a graph of values against non-continuous dates using R?

Tags: r, graph, statistics

I have a list of about 50 values and corresponding non-continuous dates in a pdf of which I need to make a time series graph in R. How do I do this?

No response can be too detailed or basic. Thanks.

Comment: This may be me, but when you say pdf do you mean a pdf file (i.e. portable document format) or a probability density function ?  I'm assuming a pdf document file which is harder to extract data from automatically, it might be easiest to copy/paste from your pdf viewer app into a text file, then read that.

Comment: Yes, sorry it is a pdf file I mean. It involved some labour-intensive deleting due to the columns but it looks like it will work better now. Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure whether to post as an answer or not. In the Adobe Reader on the Mac, one can hold down the option key while doing a select and copy and then dragging is restricted to a columnar rectangle rather than going across the entire page. It is really a time save for multi-column tables in pdf documents, which otherwise do not copy properly because they come across with no field separators. The other OSes may have similar option-key devices.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with PaulHurleyuk that your question is ambiguous because of the term "pdf". It's also ambiguous in how you want to represent the non-continuous aspect. If you want to just plot values as lines and ignore  spacing  but do not have NA values then this works:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(Sys.Date()+sample(1:75, 50)),  
                      Value = rnorm(50))
plot(dataset[order(dataset[,1]), ], type="l")
```

If you want to have discontinuities at the date where there are NA values, and you want to have gaps in the plotted values, then:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(Sys.Date()+1:50), Value = rnorm(50))  
dataset[sample(1:50, 10), 2] <- NA
plot(dataset[order(dataset[,1]), ], type="l")
```

Comment: How could "non-continuous dates in a probability density function" make sense as a time series?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(chron)
dataset <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(chron(runif(50, 0, 365))), Value = rnorm(50))
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Date, y = Value)) + geom_line()
```